# while Running On Android, I got this error. Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am Beginner in React Native. I created some Projects but I couldn't build them on android. Can you please help me in that? I got this error whenever I run on android

```
info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/mubirai/Desktop/AIsoft/reactNative/AwesomeProject/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/mubirai/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/6hrksilieebwgbc2tk6l5h8hd).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 402ms

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/mubirai/Desktop/AIsoft/reactNative/AwesomeProject/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/mubirai/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/6hrksilieebwgbc2tk6l5h8hd).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 402ms

    at makeError (/Users/mubirai/Desktop/AIsoft/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/mubirai/Desktop/AIsoft/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/mubirai/Desktop/AIsoft/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/mubirai/Desktop/AIsoft/reactNative/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I tried many solution but didn't get anything in response

Comment: i think you should clean gradle and try it again

Comment: @HazratGafulov I already cleaned that once but still facing the issue. project is running on iOS but whenever I run on android I got this error